# String returning null after bufferedreader

Tags: java, string

I grab a line from a text file from a url as a string, and the string returns the correct value. However, if i call the string after the read the string returns null.

I have no idea what's going on and would appreciate any guidance.

```
    static protected String readURL() {
    String u = "http://adamblanchard.co.uk/push.txt";
    URL url;
    InputStream is;
    InputStreamReader isr;
    BufferedReader r;


    try {
      System.out.println("Reading URL: " + u);
      url = new URL(u);
      is = url.openStream();
      isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
      r = new BufferedReader(isr);
      do {
        str = r.readLine();
        if (str != null)
          System.out.println(str);  //returns correct string
      } while (str != null);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid URL");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Can not connect");
    }
    System.out.println(str);  //str returns "null"
    return str;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BufferedReader.readLine()` method returns `null` when it reaches the end of file.

Your program appears to be reading and printing each line in the file, and finally printing the value of `str` at the bottom.  Given that the condition for terminating the read loop is that `str` is `null`, that (rather unsurprisingly) is what is printed, and what is returned by the method.

Answer (score 1):

Hai Buddy.Look at u'r do-while loop.

```
do {
        str = r.readLine();
        if (str != null)
          System.out.println(str);  
      } while (str != null); //i.e exit loop when str==null
```

So,str outside the loop is null

Answer (score 0):

You loop until end of file within

```
do {
    str = r.readLine();
    if (str != null)
      System.out.println(str);  //returns correct string
} while (str != null);
```

Thus afterwards `str` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `do while loop` use  a `while loop` to check for appropriate condition and print the resultant string.

```
   Example construct:           

   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/input.txt"));          
   while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {            
   //write your logic here. Print the required string.          
   }
```