# doInBackground throws NullPointerException for no reason

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

In here the code with `BufferedReader`and `line = reader.readLine()` works

```
public class WeatherService extends AsyncTask<TaskParams, Void, String> {
private WeatherServiceCallback callback;
private Exception exception;

public WeatherService(WeatherServiceCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(TaskParams... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
                params[0].getLat() + "&lon=" + params[0].getLon() +
                "&units=" + TaskParams.getUnits() +
                "&type=" + TaskParams.getAccuracy() + "&lang=" + TaskParams.getLanguage() +
                "&appid=10660a09a9fb335d72f576f7aa1bbe5b");

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        exception = e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        exception = e;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    if (s == null && exception != null)
    {
        callback.serviceFailure(exception);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(s);
        Parameters parameters = new Parameters();
        parameters.poopulate(data);
        callback.serviceSuccess(parameters);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I copy-pasted code to other class since it has very similar functionality and now for no reason I'm getting `NullPointerException` in `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)` and I have no idea why since as I said it's copy-pasted (I only changed URL and object returned if serivce succeeds)

```
public class PollutionService extends AsyncTask<TaskParams, Void, String>
{

private PollutionServiceCallback callback;
private Exception exception;
private URLConnection connection;
private InputStream inputStream;
private InputStreamReader streamReader;
private BufferedReader reader;

public PollutionService(PollutionServiceCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(TaskParams... params) {
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/pollution/v1/co/" + params[0].getLat() +
                "," + params[0].getLon() + "/current.json?&appid=10660a09a9fb335d72f576f7aa1bbe5b");

        try
        {
            connection = url.openConnection();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            exception = new Exception("Connection error");
        }

        try
        {
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            exception = new Exception("Input stream error");
        }

        try
        {
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        }

        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            exception = new Exception("Input stream reader error");
        }

        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        }

        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            exception = new Exception("Buffered reader error");
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        exception = e;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    if (s == null && exception != null)
    {
        callback.pollutionServiceFailure(exception);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(s);
        PollutionParameters parameters = new PollutionParameters();
        parameters.poopulate(data);
        callback.pollutionServiceSuccess(parameters);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Any clue?

**EDIT**
This is rewritten code for `PollutionActivity`. Callback function `serviceFailure` prints now the URL address on my phone's screen

```
public class PollutionService extends AsyncTask<TaskParams, Void, String>
{

private PollutionServiceCallback callback;
private Exception exception;

public PollutionService(PollutionServiceCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(TaskParams... params) {
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/pollution/v1/co/" + params[0].getLat() +
                "," + params[0].getLon() + "/current.json?&appid=10660a09a9fb335d72f576f7aa1bbe5b");

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        exception = e;
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        exception = e;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    if (s == null && exception != null)
    {
        callback.pollutionServiceFailure(exception);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(s);
        PollutionParameters parameters = new PollutionParameters();
        parameters.poopulate(data);
        callback.pollutionServiceSuccess(parameters);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Debugging showed me that code jumps to exception after 
`InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();`

Comment: please add your crash log

Comment: okay, give me a sec

Comment: @USKMobility see edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: PollutionService.java line number 89 ?

Comment: Do you ever print the exception stacktrace? It seems each individual catch statement overrides the previous exception

Comment: Hmm I have a callback that catches those exceptions and them prints them

Comment: @USKMobility yes line 89 that is with readLine in while loop

Comment: Reader will be null if you hit `Buffered reader error`, however that exception result is never printed when you hit the NullPointerException

Comment: Shall I then catch just general Exception?

Comment: I suggest you use directly Log the exceptions and worry about the callback later (and fix the reassignment of the exception because you catch one, then continue on to try code that throws new exceptions, then catch those, and repeat)

Comment: Yes catch general exception and print the exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361353/string-returning-null-after-bufferedreader

Comment: Wait a sec I'm rewriting a code

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting NPE for reader then it means that reader is not getting initialized and going null.Your code is getting crash at line 23 and 89. So I believe that the problem is right at the start somewhere and not at the point itself, may be some object is going null like connection.Since line number is not displayed here.Check null pointer for every object like if (connection!=null). Since the initial data is coming null,maybe input stream or some other data,hence your reader object is not getting initialized.Also check if you are getting value for every object in debug.

Comment: Going to debug in a sec

Comment: Exactly so there is your problem, and not at the line you are talking about.It means your first line url.openconnection must not be working. Check if it is working properly.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Check if connection object is null, try to see its value.

Comment: please add connection.connect() after your connection object and see once.

Comment: No effect unfortunately